# How to limit an API key to unidirectional write without read to a single OneDrive folder?

Tags: onedrive

I want a single API key to be able to backup files and folders to a single **Microsoft OneDrive Business** folder.

- It has to be unidirectional, even if someone steals this API key, the attacker could only send data, not read them and not delete them.

I feel my requirement very basic but I struggle a lot.

- **Is that possible? How?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to grant an app write-only access. If you don't mind, please request that feature on [UserVoice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913708/) so others can vote on it.

Depending on your requirements, it may be possible to do something that works for you, though. The [createUploadSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online) API produces a write-only URL targeted at a single file. If you have a trusted component of your app (that's allowed to have full read/write access), you can let that app call `createUploadSession` and hand off the URL to a less-trusted piece of code that does the actual upload. I hope this suggestion helps.

Comment: This feature would have been very nice and can be deployed anywhere without risking anything. This API permission proxy/controller was my second choice. Thanks!